# Getting rid of singletons?

Tags: javascript, oop, singleton

I'm writing a web app that is getting too complex and I'd like to simplify how my components work together. I have a few singletons that "know" about all the objects they have to do with.

For example I have a `windowSystem` that holds an array of all the `window` objects that exist. All of the windows don't know anything about each other but I have this irritating singleton there for things like a `closeAllWindows()` function or `if(sameWindowExists()) { return }` -type things that (I think) require some sort of way to keep track of all the `windows`. I create one `windowSystem` instance when my program starts.

It feels like these are unnecessary because they know more than they should. What other options do I have?

**Edit:** Here is some code that shows the creation of various `_____System`s

```
var refDate = usDate.now();

    var eventSystem = usEventSystem($("#topLevelElement")),
        backend = usBackend(eventSystem.trigger),
        windowSystem = usWindowSystem($("#windows"), eventSystem.registerEvent),
        timelineSystem = usTimelineSystem($("#view"), 
                                        backend.getEvents, 
                                        usDate.now().shift({ hours:-6 }), 
                                        usDate.now().shift({ hours:6 }),
                                        eventSystem.registerEvent,
                                        eventSystem.unregisterEvent,
                                        windowSystem.createWindow);

    usWindow.setRegisterEventFunc(eventSystem.registerEvent).setUnregisterEventFunc(eventSystem.unregisterEvent);
```

What I really dislike about it is that I'm passing lots of functions from other systems into each other (and they in turn pass those on to the objects -like a `window`- they create) which doesn't seem to scale well.

Comment: What you made sounds like a window manager - there's nothing really wrong with that, but it's kind of hard to tell without being able to see more code and understand the complexity of what you're talking about.

Comment: Ok, so you have this class and you've just created one instance of it. Has adding logic to that class to prevent you from creating more instances, actually helped you? Have you been tempted to create more instances? If you had accidentally written code to create another instance, how long would it take for the Singleton logic to actually alert you to that fact? - On another note, your complaint is that these instances "know more than they should"; what exactly does the WindowSystem know other than "here are a bunch of Window instances"?

Comment: @Karl, @Stephen: I added code. There's too many functions being thrown back and forth between `systems` which makes me think there's got to be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having your window managing logic in a singleton sitting above the windows you could try transferring it to a base class that all windows inherit from. It could look something like:

```
function BaseWindow() {
    //whatever common constructor logic you may want
    //such as creating an id
    this.id = this.id + 1
}

//this is static
BaseWindow.activeWindow = null;

//this is a property visible to each window instance but is updated by the base class
BaseWindow.prototype.id = 0;

//this is a property visible to each window instance but may be overridden by a subclass
BaseWindow.prototype.name = "BaseWindow";

//this is function visible to each window instance
BaseWindow.prototype.show = function ( ) {
    //hide BaseWindow.activeWindow then show "this" window;
};


function WindowA() {
    //do some window specific stuff like set the window name
    this.name = "WindowA";
}

WindowA.prototype = new BaseWindow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Manual dependency injection could be provided by one singleton.  I know you are trying to get rid of those, but if you had a single one that tracked all your interesting instances (like windows) you could say something like `Injector.get("Window", "Debug");` to grab whatever window instance your Debug code wants.  This still gives you injection--a different window could be provided to the Debug class if needed, and the configuration of provided class instances could be configured in a number of ways (Data, hard-coded, etc).

You could also then use `Injector.getAll("Window")` to get and close them all.

I realize you've still got a singleton, but at least it's just one and it provides you some flexibility down the line to reconfigure your classes in one place.

Comment: Java isn't Javascript.  Though some concepts may transfer between the two, what Spring does won't help someone unless they want to emulate Spring in JS -- and that can be a lot of work.

Comment: I changed the suggestion--still suggesting injection but manually instead of automatically.  Shouldn't be too much work if done that way.